# Construct RSA Public Key in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, typescript, rsa

I have a c# web api that passes a public key to a React app. I need to use that public key to encrypt a payload/message and then send it over back to my api. However, I am having trouble reconstructing the public key in the front end. Let me explain.

The app does not use https but only http. Given that this is the case, I went ahead and generated public and private keys in c#, like so:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    RSAParameters publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    RSAParameters privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
}
```

The public key yields byte arrays for the Modulus (n) and Exponent (e) parameters, which can be used to reconstruct the public key (I've tested that on the backend). So, I then convert the n and e into base64 strings and send them over to the client.

Now, in my react app, I am using JSEncrypt library to encrypt the payload with the public key from the backend ([example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jsencrypt-example?file=index.js)). But it is failing. Here is my js:

```
const encryptMessage = (messageToEncrypt) => {
if (publicKeyParts?.length === 2) {
  const encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
  // publicKeyParts is a string[] with the exponent stored in index 0
  // and the modulus stored in index 1
  encrypt.setPublicKey(`${publicKeyParts[1]}${publicKeyParts[0]}`);

  let data = {
    payload: messageToEncrypt
  }

  let encryptedPayload = encrypt.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data));
  return encryptedPayload;
}
```

}

The encrypted message is false and does not work. I think it has to do with my public key's format. Here is my public key generated from the c# (and converted to base64):

8NHGP6WqPGgHa5Q+15V5z+SI7XAvIgMVjbNuGdmlvHoLY2kutP5u+m1lcJpcj49aVMFnoo0eJ5nBIMXVMw1Qz0EpR3BreHp0X0Yfavf2E1lyIl5oyQFTpuzvMu0U3DebLvRezICn66CmFJxnsuERTM5NQ+vE5/3WUx4uMI8jKLE=

When I compare this to other public keys I notice that my key has characters that I don't see in other working public keys (like the one in the example I linked above).

Is there a conversion that I am missing? I have scoured websites but am not able to see what could be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken a look at the example you have linked in your question. In the example, they are using [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) RSA keys, both public and private. The public key they are using

```
const pub_key = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDeoeE0ytVpM2uDidhMFilE13nXHfEIQqfMJ1TUqGotm6HI72h6ZEqf2PhZEcZkyV34u1d822dqoJMs00IlQiNsshdzU2cIrDYhqPNRfkcHQXCzZoep/BAUvUQrDouhSl89BQXzxK45CLdoy2kcvqqXb2U+GK9LmSqxJSWPEZDYZQIDAQAB'
```

can be written as

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDeoeE0ytVpM2uDidhMFilE
13nXHfEIQqfMJ1TUqGotm6HI72h6ZEqf2PhZEcZkyV34u1d822dqoJMs00IlQiNss
hdzU2cIrDYhqPNRfkcHQXCzZoep/BAUvUQrDouhSl89BQXzxK45CLdoy2kcvqqX
b2U+GK9LmSqxJSWPEZDYZQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

meaning that they are using a public key in X.509 format with modulus `dea1e134cad569336b8389d84c162944d779d71df10842a7cc2754d4a86a2d9ba1c8ef687a644a9fd8f85911c664c95df8bb577cdb676aa0932cd3422542236cb21773536708ac3621a8f3517e47074170b36687a9fc1014bd442b0e8ba14a5f3d0505f3c4ae3908b768cb691cbeaa976f653e18af4b992ab125258f1190d865` and public exponent `10001`.

If you take a look at the library JSEncrypt [code](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/24e69d8b197b3322d17500af858f3e44e4276f1d/src/JSEncrypt.ts#L69C8-L69C8), you will find that the method `setPublicKey` is expecting a key in a string format. It doesn't specify a format in the method comments but from the example you have provided and some other online example I have found, this method is expecting the public RSA key in a PEM format. More importantly, in the [`README`](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/master/README.md) they have stated that their library uses PEM format. **This is the reason your code isn't working**. You are sending to this method a key which is composed of concatenated, base64 encoded, public key parameters, exponent and modulus. Here you have two options:

1. Create a whole public RSA PEM key in the backend and send it to the frontend.
2. Generate a public key in your frontend code from your public key parameters.

If you take a look at the library repo, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/146) about creating a public key from its parameters. Here is a copy of the code from the aforementioned issue on how to create a key from its parameters:

```
import JSEncrypt from 'jsencrypt';
import { parseBigInt } from 'jsencrypt/lib/lib/jsbn/jsbn';

const nStr = 'BB6FE79432CC6EA2D8F970675A5A87BFBE1AFF0BE63E879F2AFFB93644D4D2C6D000430DEC66ABF47829E74B8C5108623A1C0EE8BE217B3AD8D36D5EB4FCA1D9';
const eStr = '010001';

const n = parseBigInt(nStr, 16);
const e = parseInt(eStr, 16);

const encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
const key = encrypt.getKey();
key.parsePropertiesFrom({ n, e });
```

Finally, be mindful of which padding scheme, [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) or [PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1), you are using when encrypting data. Also, don't forget you use an appropriate key length when creating your keys (you might find [this](https://www.nist.gov/publications/transitioning-use-cryptographic-algorithms-and-key-lengths) useful).

Comment: that worked, thx! In my backend, instead of converting the modulus byte array into a base64 string, I converted it into a string representation of a hexadecimal value like your example showed. Then I just used the code snippet and it encoded it just fine.